# Regularity for a div-curl system

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, regularity

Let  $Q = [0,1]^3$ be the unit cube in $ \mathbb{R}^3$, and let $U \subset Q$ be a simply-connected subdomain with smooth boundary. Suppose $g \: \colon Q \to \mathbb{R}^3$ is a non-negative smooth field with support contained in $U$, and such that $\textrm{div}\, g = 0$ in $Q$.

I am able to prove the existence of a $Q$-periodic solution $v \in W^{1, 2}(Q)$ to
\begin{align}
\text{curl}\, v & = g \quad \text{ in } Q\, ,\\
\text{div} \, v & = 0 \quad \text{ in } Q\, .
\end{align}
My question is now:

> Can we prove that $v \in C^1(Q, \mathbb{R}^3)$?

As $g$ is smooth, I expect such a result. However, I haven't been able to find a regularity result for this div-curl system.

Comment: [This](http://arxiv.org/abs/1408.2469) is an overkill for your problem, so is Bourgain-Brezis, JEMS 9 (2007), 277-315 [Corollary 12 in particular]. The system is also called a Hodge system. And sometimes you will also find older literature from studies having to do with electromagnetism.

Comment: In your case in particular, you can use elementary Fourier methods to show that the $\dot{H}^1$ norm of $v$ is bounded by $g$ in $L^2$. Now commute with partial derivatives $\partial_i$ to get higher sobolev bounds and use Sobolev embedding to come back down to $C^1$.

Comment: If you add the curl of the first equation to the gradient of the second equation, you get $\Delta v = \mathrm{curl} \ g$. Integrating the dot product of this with $v$ by parts gives the bound mentioned by Willie.

Comment: I don't know what _non-negative_ means for a 3-dim field.

Comment: @JeanDuchon You are right; the term "non-negative" is not well-defined for a vector field. However, let me define the term "non-negative vector field $v = (v_1, v_2, v_3)$" by imposing that all components $v_1$, $v_2$, and $v_3$ are non negative.

Comment: If v is Q-periodic, then g better have zero average. If it is also "non-negative," then that does not leave too many options.

Comment: @MichaelRenardy: Your are right, of course! I noticed this recently.

Comment: However, I am actually interested in a $C^1$-smooth vector field $v \colon Q \setminus U \to \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $ \text{curl} \, v = 0$ in $Q \setminus U$ and such that the line integral $\int_{\gamma} v \neq 0$, where $\gamma \colon [0, 1] \to \Omega$ is a continuous path with $\gamma([0, 1]) \subset \partial U$. For the sake of simplicity, let us assume that $U$ is a cylinder in the middle $Q$ connecting $ \lbrace 0\rbrace \times [0, 1]$ and $\lbrace 1 \rbrace \times [0, 1]$. I thought, a solution to this div-curl system could be such a vector field. Apparently, this is not the case.